# Select * from Athena table is not giving results even after 3 hours

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, amazon-quicksight

Need help with a scenario that I am facing with table created through Athena CTAS. There is around 40GB of data in the background and format is parquet with SNAPPY compression. When I do a :
Select * from tablename
on the table then it scans all the data within a minute but then gets stuck there running.
[image]
It has a total of 894473053 records.

I am also trying to ingest all this data into QuickSight and that too times out.

We have tried reducing the partitions and that too has not had an effect.

Comment: How many files are there in that table? You probably don't want to do a `SELECT *` in the Amazon Athena console -- sending that amount of data would be massive.